# XNA 3.1 Laggy movement

Tags: xna, game-physics

I have **Windows XP SP3.**

I created the default XNA project in version 3.1 and added these simple lines to the pregenerated code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(80, 80, 100, 100);  
    Texture2D textureTrain;     

    public Game1()
    {            
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);     
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        //TargetElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
    }
...

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);      

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        textureTrain = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MyBitmap1");
    }
...

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        rectangle.X = rectangle.X + 1;
        rectangle.Y = rectangle.Y + 1;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();        
        spriteBatch.Draw(textureTrain, rectangle, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

as simple as this ! But the movement is very laggy, it flickers, I can't even look at it.
If I compare it to some flash games it's incomparable. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that XNA 4.0 has been out for a while and is what you should be using now.

Comment: I tested your code (albeit on Vista in XNA 4), and there was no flickering, stuttering, or lag of any kind (and I wouldn't expect there to be on XP and XNA 3.1 either). Are you able to play GPU-accelerated games normally, lag-free? Is there code you haven't posted?

Comment: Well are you sure that there is not a difference between running XNA on XP vs vista and later? I've never played a game on this pc.. Yes, it is the full code posted. Could it be that I miss some drivers / libraries to access the gpu ? Anyways, such a simple example must be emulated by cpu smoothly, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because your are using the X and Y components of the Rectangle, your calculation will be rounded to the nearest whole number. You want granularity in this case, fine, precise movements.

i.e.

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(0.1f, 0.1f);
//Some Arbitrary movement
float speed = 0.008f;
position.X += (float)((speed * position.X);
position.Y += (float)((speed * position.Y);

spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(textureTrain, position, rectangle, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: It annoys me when people suggest this, as by default, XNA compensates for lag by skipping the draw method. You should really and truthfully not need to do this unless you're running your game in fixed timestep.

Comment: I changed my answer so that it's more correct, is this what you expected @Ruirize?

Comment: What is then with the IsFixedTimeStep ? Could it affect the fluency of the movement?

Comment: Thanks for changing it. I just see so many these days mistaking old tricks for what XNA fixes automatically. IsFixedTimeStep basically controls frame skipping. Your game will drop frames if it's lagging. Setting this to true disables this behaviour. But it shouldn't cause flickering.

Comment: And what do you recommend? Fixed or not fixed time stepping for a 2d game?

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me: It depends on the kinds of calculations you are doing. Fixed is the "safest" and easiest, because it will always work. If you are doing calculations like `position += velocity * frameTime`, then fixed time steps will ensure stability. If you are doing calculations like `position = startPosition + velocity * totalTime`, then it doesn't matter if you use variable time-step.

Comment: Also -1 to the answer here because it's wrong. A `Rectangle` being moved in 1px increments each frame is very smooth (especially with a fixed time-step, which is the default). Moving by sub-pixels isn't going to improve things. Also your code has a number of errors in it.